# Reinitialization of value in for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, while-loop

In the following `for` loop, code does not work and value of i cannot be reinitialized

```
 int k = 150;
        
       for(int i = 9;i>1;i--)
       {
          while(k>0)
          {
          
          if( k % i == 0) 
            {
                res = res * 10 + i;
                k = k/i;
                i= 9;
            }
           
          }

        cout<<res;
```

But Here when i use `while` loop the code works and value of i can be reinitialized

```
 int k= 150; 
  int res=0;
  int i = 9;

      while(k>0 && i > 1)
      {
      
      if(k % i == 0) 
        {
            res = res * 10 + i;
            k = k/i;
            i = 9;

        }
        
       i--; 
       
     }

    cout<<res;
```

Comment: Define "does not work" because you haven't even told us what the code is supposed to do. Define "cannot be reinitialized" because `i= 9;` certainly will set `i` back to 9. Please give that info as well as the exact expected result vs actual result.

Comment: @kaylum the code extracts the factors of the given number  k and makes a new number with the factors. Number is stored in res.

Comment: That info belongs in the question and not in comments. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69503586/edit) the post to add it. And you still haven't explained what "doesn't work" means.

Answer (score 1):

Try using dry run in these cases:-

```
 int k = 150;
        
       for(int i = 9;i>1;i--)
       {
          while(k>0)
          {
          
          if( k % i == 0) 
            {
                res = res * 10 + i;
                k = k/i;
                i= 9;
            }
           
          }
       }

        cout<<res;
```

In this code you can see that in the first iteration of the while loop will go under infinite loop as the if condition is not satisfied and you not altering the value of k or i which leads to infinite loop (the while never stops).